# ClassNotFoundException io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer for new Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-initializr

I created a new Spring Boot project with spring initializr  with the dependencies:

- Spring Modulith
- Spring Boot Actuator

The actual [configuration](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.2.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=modulith,actuator).
Without changing anything starting the application gives me the error

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-02-17T23:26:15.088+01:00  INFO 10544 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 10544 (D:\projects\demo\build\classes\java\main started by fabian in D:\projects\demo)
2024-02-17T23:26:15.090+01:00  INFO 10544 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-17T23:26:15.484+01:00  WARN 10544 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.modulith.runtime.autoconfigure.SpringModulithRuntimeAutoConfiguration.modulithsApplicationRuntime
2024-02-17T23:26:15.492+01:00  INFO 10544 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-02-17T23:26:15.505+01:00 ERROR 10544 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.modulith.runtime.autoconfigure.SpringModulithRuntimeAutoConfiguration.modulithsApplicationRuntime
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:183) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.modulith.observability.autoconfigure.ModuleObservabilityAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:483) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:360) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:417) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$1(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:749) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:681) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:247) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:240) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:230) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:183) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:158) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/tracing/Tracer
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Removing either of the dependencies `Spring Modulith` or `Spring Boot Actuator` solves the error.

This is the generated `build.gradle` file using the described settings:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springModulithVersion', "1.1.2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-core'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-actuator'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-observability'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.modulith:spring-modulith-bom:${springModulithVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I would expect the application to simply start with the default configuration. What am I missing?

Comment: Confirmed bug with spring-initializr https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-modulith/issues/501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your instructions and indeed got the same error.
After trying to add several dependencies, I added this:

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
```

I think since we are using spring-modulith-observability which likely requires Micrometer Tracing functionality.By adding the dependency it brings in the necessary Micrometer Tracing components and bridges them with OpenTelemetry, which appears to be used by spring-modulith-observability. This resolved the error because the Tracer class is now available in the classpath.

Comment: Solves the issue. Adding `implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing'` only also works. But both solutions add a field with 50 spaces to the log output. Not sure why yet